# Can 2 Relationships be related in an ER Diagram?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing an ER for a Dummy Social Networking site where I need to relate 2 Relationships . Specifically, as per the diagram attached, I am relating Posts relation and Followed By (Followers) relation with a new relation 'can see'.

That is, Followers can see Posts of the user they follow. I need Posts because it will have the UserID of the user who posted Blip with BlipID. Diagram is not complete yet, so ignore Participants, constraints etc. 
Any suggestions on this, please?

[image: ER Diagram Image]

Comment: But why do you have both "Follows" and "Followed By" relationships? Aren't these the same thing?

Comment: I think the relation `can_see` should be between `Users` and `Blip`, since you want the relation about users seeing blips, right?

Comment: This is specific requirement that User's Profile should contain IDs of all his Followers and all whom he Follows. That's why I included both relations. However, while converting to Relational, I'll be using one table because it essentially is the same relationship.

Comment: Yes, I want the Users to see the blip, but they should be Following the person who posted the blip. That's why I'm confused, where to put this relation. Although now I think, I could use a View later on to satisfy this.

Comment: If your case is "User can read posts from the users they are following" then, you already have it, because you can get the posts of those users you are following by select query.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments suggest, I believe you don't need both Followed By and Follows entities.

Rather, it should go something like this:

```
Users:
UserId (PK)
<User info columns>

UserFollowsUser:
FollowerId (FK from Users.UserId)
FollowedId (FK from Users.UserId)
<other info, if needed>
```

Now, I don't know if you want to add restrictions to a following relationship (i.e. do you want to restrict a follower from some of the posts? or can he see all the posts of the user he follows?).

Because, if you don't need any restrictions, you don't need the **"can read"** entity.

In Post table, you just need the UserId FK, and the follower can read any Post which has UserId = FollowedId.